# Is there any reason (based on the laws of kashrut) that one cannot brine kashered meat?

Tags: food, kashrut-kosher, meat

On Seasoned Advice, there is a question regarding [brining kosher birds](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/19111/brining-a-kosher-bird). Is there any halachic reason that one cannot brine meat that has already been kashered?

Comment: Not a good answer, so I'll post it as a comment, but: Not that I've ever heard of. I've marinated/brined (is there a difference?) chicken, myself.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12146

Comment: Welcome to the site, Martha F., and thanks for bringing your question here. I hope you stick around and enjoy the site.

Comment: I have to ask, does that actually taste good? *shudder* Brining and marinating are NOT the same thing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can brine koshered meat. That is what corned beef is.

However, it is not quite correct to say,

> Once it's been salted & soaked, you can do whatever you want with it.
>   (Corned beef is usually salted & soaked, then pickled, if I'm not
>   mistaken.) – Shalom

It is not permitted to eat it uncooked. 
It is wasteful to throw it away.

Comment: Source for "It is not permitted to eat it uncooked", please?

Comment: @user15972 Welcome to Judaism.SE! Look forward to seeing you around.

Answer (score 5):

As long as the original salt/blood mixture is washed off (which is required of the Koshering agency), you can re-salt without the kashering requirements.  (Shulchan Aruch Y.D. [69:20](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9145&st=&pgnum=314))

Comment: 69:20 is talking about salting it. Brining, if I'm not mistaken (though perhaps the question should define it), is in liquid.

Comment: @msh210, True, brine is salt water (plus you can add stuff).  The only two possible problems that I see are a) The sages might have decreed not to re-salt anything, at least not in a non-halachic fashion like soaking it in the salt, or b) the salt solution is putting some non-kosher substance back into the meat/foul.  This halacha allows you to re-salt even in a non-holed keli as long as you washed the original blood-salt off very well.  Am I missing another scenario?

Comment: Once it's been salted & soaked, you can do whatever you want with it. (Corned beef is usually salted & soaked, then pickled, if I'm not mistaken.)

Comment: Yeah, I was trying to find a source, but like Avraham H., I guess the best source is maasim bchol yom.

Answer (score 2):

Here in Borough Park, in a Satmar butcher shop, they are selling pickled chicken, and friends of mine where I eat shabbbos have said that they'd had pickled turkey. I'm pretty sure pickled means brined.

Comment: Oh, of course, many stores sell pickled tongue. Is that the same as brined? As I mentioned in a comment on YDK's answer, the question might do with a definition. Incidentally, welcome to the site, Avraham H.; I hope stick around and enjoy it. If you register your username, you will gain access to more of the site's features. Oh, and what is "B.P."?

Comment: Guessing Borough Park

Comment: @Avi, You guessed right. And actually I have personally have never heard the term brined. the process I have heard in the butcher shops was, maybe still is "pickled in brine". Pickling being the process, and brine the liquid mixture used to marinate.